# updating and exporting an array of id's via entityframework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

from a webapi im providing the list of Specialites a Member has to populate a html control which requires these selected items to be in the form of an array of string id's 
i.e. `["1","2","3"]`

the code below gives me a collection of complex objects, is it possible to get an array of strings which contain the speciality_id?

```
   var v = db.MemberSpecialities.Where(s => s.member_id == id).Select(u => new {u.speciality_id.Value}).ToArray()


public partial class MemberSpecialities
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> member_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> speciality_id { get; set; }    
    }
```

additionally when i get the list back with the changes, is there a quick way of updating the values using linq, (i.e. deleting the old entries and adding the new entries?)

Comment: that doesnt work, debugging throws an error on the tostring ef doesnt allow it.

Comment: how about something like this: `string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join("," db.MemberSpecialities.Where(s => s.member_id == id).Select(u => string.Format("\"{0}\"", u.speciality_id))));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var v = db.MemberSpecialities.Where(s => s.member_id == id).Select(u => u.speciality_id.Value).Cast<string>().ToArray();
```